# Silverlight: How do I set the style of a control within a control in a resource?

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml

For example, here is some code to populate a listbox with 2 listboxes:

```
<ListBox x:Name="LayoutRoot" Width="200" Height="400" Style="{StaticResource ListStyle}" >
    <ListBoxItem>
        <ListBox>
            <ListBoxItem>11</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>12</ListBoxItem>
        </ListBox>
    </ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem>
        <ListBox>
            <ListBoxItem>21</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>22</ListBoxItem>
        </ListBox>
    </ListBoxItem>
</ListBox>
```

The inner list boxes both appear displaying their content in a vertical list.  Now, I know how to get a single list box to display its content horizontally, and I know how to do this by setting the style in a resource.  What I can't figure out is how to set it in a resource that I can just apply once to the outer listbox and not every time I add another inner listbox (i.e. apply it to each and every inner listbox).

Here is my umpteenth failed attempt:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="ListStyle" TargetType="ListBox">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ListBox>
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ListBox>
                                <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                        <toolkit:WrapPanel/>
                                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                            </ListBox>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

If I haven't made it clear, what I want to see in my listbox is 11, 12 side-by-side in the first row and 21, 22 side-by-side in the second row.

Comment: There will be a way to do this using `ItemTemplate` however are you really sure you want this interface? Do you really need a selectable list of selectable lists of items? I've noted the often ListBox is being used for layout purposes only, which is fine but may not always be the best choice. Clarify why you want to use ListBox over say a simple set of StackPanels and/or ItemsControl with a ScrollViewer. Perhaps it would be good if you describe your goal rather than your choice of implementing the as yet unknown to us goal.

Comment: At the moment I have 4 list boxes, 2 of which contain colors and the other 2 contain bits of images.  All the list boxes are populated from collections.  Rather than 4 listboxes it would be neater to populate 4 listboxes in code and add them to the 1 list box on the UI.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Silverlight 4, you can create an implicit style.  You do this by not including a Key in the Style declaration.  This will implicitly apply the style to all of the controls within the scope of that resource.  You then need to also explicitly set the ItemsPanel of the Root ListBox to layout Vertically.

```
<ListBox x:Name="LayoutRoot" Width="200" Height="400">
    <ListBox.Resources>
      <Style TargetType="ListBox">
        <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
            <Setter.Value>
              <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <toolkit:WrapPanel/>
              </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
      </Style>
    </ListBox.Resources>
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
      <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
      </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ListBoxItem>
        <ListBox>
            <ListBoxItem>11</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>12</ListBoxItem>
        </ListBox>
    </ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem>
        <ListBox>
            <ListBoxItem>21</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>22</ListBoxItem>
        </ListBox>
    </ListBoxItem>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure how this applies to my question?

Comment: To be a bit more specific, the XAML code for setting the style that I have posted does not work - that is the problem - and I do not want to implicitly set the style of all my outer or inner list boxes the same way.

Comment: Sorry, just realized that your XAMl was wrong.  Fixing.

You can create an implicit style within the resources of the Outer ListBox.  That way every Inner ListBox will implicitly get that style.  That should solve your problem of not needing to explicitly set the style on each inner ListBox.

Comment: Issue is that the outer list box gets the style as well and I don't want that.  I want a vertical list of horizontal lists not a wrapped list of horizontal lists.

Comment: You can fix that by explicitly setting the ItemsPanel on the Root ListBox.  I tested this out in Silverlight 4 and it works like you want.